# Camera preview stretched in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have set the camera preview be full-screen to meet a particular UI, however the camera is full-screen, but it is very stretched.

Where am I going wrong?

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: controller.value.aspectRatio / deviceRatio,
          child: new AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: new CameraPreview(controller),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

I have attached a photo below. AS you can see, it is very blurred, and stretched, when compared against the button.

EDIT: Here is the error I am receiving:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The Method '[]' was called on Null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)
```

EDIT - Here is the full camera page,

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'MyApp/main.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  Function setData;
  Camera({Key key, this.setData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<Camera> {
  CameraController controller;
  List cameras;
  int selectedCameraIndex;
  String imgPath;
  var image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screen resolution doesn't necessarily match you camera resolution, you should use camera's resolution and aspect ratio to get proper image.

Take a look at the [aspectRatio](https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/camera/CameraValue/aspectRatio.html) property that you can get from `CameraValue` after initialization.

---

**UPDATE:**

Actually, you don't even need `aspectRatio`. You can just use the `DevicePreview` directly. If the parent widget is fullscreen, the preview will be fullscreen as well. E.g. the official example in [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package is rendered like that:

[image]

Example code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  cameras = await availableCameras();
  runApp(CameraApp());
}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraAppState createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  CameraController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But you shouldn't scale it to match your screen size, as they can be completely different. You can just leave CameraPreview widget. Take a look at the example in [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package readme: it's already fullscreen.

Comment: I marketed as correct, as this should be working, however, I made an edit of what is happening. If you could review, that would be awesome.

Comment: Remove `List cameras;` from `_CameraScreenState` as it shadows 
`List<CameraDescription> cameras;` defined at the top of the file.

Comment: So you need to present it in fullscreen and you cannot change the size of the preview view with `Container` for instance?

Comment: I found a way to size the camera with this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348166/how-to-square-crop-a-flutter-camera-preview

Comment: @KirillBubochkin The camera is matching the screen with this sample but the preview is still stretched since the camera aspect ratio is lower than the screen ratio. Without scale up the camera preview to fit the screen ratio I don't know how it can match. What is recommended ?