# Crop camera preview Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, crop, stretched

I am trying to crop in a square ratio my camera preview but I keep getting stretched camera even tho I tried almost everything here : [How to square crop a Flutter camera preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348166/how-to-square-crop-a-flutter-camera-preview)
But nothing worked.

[image: camera preview]

Here is my current code :

```
    return Column(
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: ClipRect(
                child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: 1 / cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: Center(
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: CameraPreview(cameraController),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```